# stripslashes security testing

Tags: php, stripslashes

I am testing how secure is to use `stripslashes()`

I tried the following :

```
  $str = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27);

  var_dump(stripslashes($str)); // string(2) " �' "
```

Then I changed it to this :

```
  $str = $_POST['input']; // %bf%27;

  var_dump(stripslashes($str)); // string(3) " �'' "
```

Then I used **curl** to send `input` data :

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'input=' . chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27));
```

but again result was : `string(3) " �'' "`

**Is it possible to get result as in First example when data is received from another server? Will it be secure to use `stripslashes()` ?**

Comment: consider reading examples given in following link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Where does the second single quote come from?

Comment: Also take a read on "PHP: the Right Way" about data filtering if you are think of ways to sanitize your code http://www.phptherightway.com/#security

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions here:

### On the security of stripslashes

`stripslashes()` is not really a secure way of handling input (that goes to a database, i assume). There are too many variables involved, like

- Target Database System
- Encoding of the database connection
- Easy-to-miss programmer errors

### On receiving POST data

Try the following file. It should serve as a basic test case for what you are investigating. I so far cannot reproduce the problem that you described.

`test.php`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="input"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<?php 

$string = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27); // yields string '¿'' (length=2)
$input = $_POST['input'];

foreach (array($string, $input) as $s) {
  var_dump(stripslashes($s));
  var_dump($s);
}

?>
</html>
```

The results that you get strongly point to an encoding problem.